# Second Monitor is not working properly on ubuntu 15.04 after changing driver

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, 15.04

I am using ubuntu 15.04 with RADEON graphics on a samsung notebook. The extra monitor that I used to Plug on it was working perfectly, until I changed the proprietary driver of my video card in Ubuntu. Now when I plug the second monitor my main screen and this extra screen start to blink and show the desktop 'translated'.

Now, the problem continues even if I change the driver of my video card. These are the options I have:

[image]

What can I do to solve this?